# Bounty on my question

Tags: discussion

I have put a 50 point bounty on my question [When does the Spanish "ll" transform to "lh", when does it transform to "ch" in Portuguese, and when does it transform to just "l"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9398/when-does-the-spanish-ll-transform-to-lh-when-does-it-transform-to-ch-in) 3 days ago. 4 days are left before the bounty expires. However, I have not yet received an answer there. I then brought my question to the chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139442/when-does-the-spanish-ll-transform-to-lh-when-does-it-transform-to-ch-in-p. I have not received a reply in the chat either. I cannot understand why people are getting so late to answer my question during the bounty period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our active community is not big and at times rather quiet. Chat rooms often remain empty or quickly go silent. Please don't let that dishearten you. Most questions are answered.

I had upvoted your question and I do hope it gets an answer, especially now you invested in a bounty. But it may well happen that the people with the knowledge and time to answer it are simply not around right now.

Comment: I answered this question and quite frankly, am a bit fed up. Spanish **did not transform ll to lh". And transform to ch in Portuguese is also wrong.. This OP has asked a number of methodologically flawed questions based on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @Lambie The accepted answer does point this out.

Comment: Yes, you can see my exchange with the person who answered. I had already put that in a comment. As I said, this OP asks questions re Spanish too that assume all kinds of things that do not exist.

Comment: @Lambie Hopefully they've learned something there.

Comment: Ai filha, aprender algo fica cada vez mas difícil, né?